# How to ping MS Access on PC-2 from PC-1

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10, windows-xp

PC-1 (Windows-XP) has MS Access 2010 database running which connects to a legacy database on server every few minutes and refreshes local tables downloading data from server.

PC-2 (Windows-10) has MS Access 2013 database running which connects to Access tables in PC-1 and runs lots of queries on them and then exports data in CSVs.

I want PC-1 to let PC-2 know when it has completed refreshing the data so PC-2 can then start running its queries. If PC-2 tries running queries while the data on PC-1 is being refreshed it could lead to data corruption and other problems.

How can I have PC-1 ping PC-2 ?

Comment: One fairly low-tech option is to create a 0-length lock file on PC-1 when update is running and delete it once that is complete. PC-2, before it starts the query process can check for the existence of that file, and only proceed if the file doesn't exist. Note that PC-2 should also create a lock file when it runs queries, so PC-1 won't start updating the db while that happens. I.e. it goes both ways.

Comment: This, or maybe easier to check since the tables are already linked, setting and clearing a flag in a settings table. You should write your comment as answer. @LoganReed

Comment: Both valuable suggestions. Will try @Andre's first and if not then Logan Reed's

Comment: @Logan Reed: If you were to write your comment as an answer, I would accept it. I ended up following the lock file route and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fairly low-tech option is to create a 0-length lock file on PC-1 when update is running and delete it once that is complete. PC-2, before it starts the query process can check for the existence of that file, and only proceed if the file doesn't exist. Note that PC-2 should also create a lock file when it runs queries, so PC-1 won't start updating the db while that happens. I.e. it goes both ways.